# Can I remove a method alias in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, alias-method

Suppose I've got a section of Ruby code where I'd like to alias a method (I don't know why; let's just suppose I have a good reason).

```
class String
    alias_method :contains?, :include?
end
```

Would it be possible for me, after this section, to *remove* this alias?

Answer (score 7):

`remove_method` should work in most cases. But if your `alias_method` overwrites an existing method, you may need to save the original via a separate `alias_method` call.

```
# assuming :contains? is already a method 
alias_method :original_contains?, :contains?
alias_method :contains?, :include?
```

Then to restore the original state:

```
alias_method :contains?, :original_contains?
remove_method :original_contains?  # optional
```

Note also that modifying a class that's used in multiple threads is prone to race conditions. And if you're trying to disallow libs from using the alias, you can't prevent that if you're calling those libs' methods while the alias exists. We might see a way to do this in ruby 2.0: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/11/30/ruby-2-0-refinements-in-practice/

It would be helpful if you could say why you want to remove the alias. If the method name did not exist before, no other libs should be affected by your monkey-patch. Also, you should consider subclassing `String` (or delegating to a string instance) rather than patching `String`.

Comment: Thanks, great tip!

Answer (score 4):

```
def hello
   puts "Hello World"
end
alias :hi :hello

hi #=> "Hello World"
undef hi
hi #=> NameError
hello #=> "Hello World"
```

EDIT: Note that this will only work on methods created on the `main` object. In order to enact this on a class, you'd need to do something like , `Hello.class_eval("undef hi")`

However, from a metaprogramming standpoint, when dealing with classes, I like the usage of `remove_method :hi` since it'll cause the method lookup to fall down and grab the method from a parent class.

```
class Nums < Array
   def include?
      puts "Just Kidding"
   end
end

n = Nums.new
n << 4 #=> [4]
n.include? #=> "Just kidding"
Nums.class_eval("remove_method :include?")
n.include? 4 #=> true
Number.class_eval("undef include?")
n.include? 4 #=> NoMethodError
```

`remove_method` is much more meta friendly.

Comment: `remove_method` is better if `hi` was originally inherited or mixed-in. Using `undef` or `undef_method` will prevent the call from propagating up the inheritance/mix-in chain.

Comment: I was actually editing my answer to reflect that while you commented =D